# is myisam table type really better for a log table (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, myisam

i've been reading up whether to use myisam or innodb for a log table (lots of writes, very few reads). While some people say that myisam is overall faster and less resource-intensive, other people say that myisam would actually be the worse choice because it only has table-level locking.

Does anybody have actual experience with this situation and care to share their recommendation ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MyISAM is good if you are either doing mostly writes with just a few queries, or mostly queries with just a few writes.

My guess is that for a log you would probably be doing only a few queries so MyISAM may be the best choice for you, but if the log is being frequently displayed and filtered in your application then you should use InnoDB.